# Convert Dictionary JSON to Typescript model

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I want to convert the following JSON object to a TypeScript interface for type safety:

```json
{
  "attributes1": {
    "myKey1": {
      "myinnerKey11": {
        "value": "value 1",
        "name": "name 1"
      },
      "myinnerKey12": {
        "value": "value 1",
        "name": "name 1",
        "otherKey": "key 2"
      }
    }
  },
  "attributes2": {
    "myKey2": {
      "myinnerKey21": {
        "value": "value 1",
        "name": "name 1"
      },
      "myinnerKey22": {
        "value": "value 1",
        "name": "name 1",
        "otherKey": "key 2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried creating the following interface:

```js
export interface IFinalObj {
    attributes1: IAttributes1;
    attributes2: IAttributes2;
}

interface IMyInnerObj {
    value: string;
    name: string;
    otherKey?: string;
}

interface IDynamicInnerKey {
    [a: string]: IMyInnerObj
}
    
interface IAttributes1 {
    myKey1: IDynamicInnerKey;
}

interface IAttributes2 {
    myKey2: IDynamicInnerKey;
}
```

I'm not sure what to do when the key's value will be changed and new objects get added.

Comment: What in your case is the "desired output" ?

Comment: What about using this tool which generates the interface for you? http://json2ts.com/ . Besides, what do you mean by "but it is not returning the desired output and the code looks messy". Interfaces returns nothing, they are just signatures and, at runtime, they do nothing at all.

Comment: it depends which properties are fixed and which ones are dynamic, then you can do better type for your class.

Comment: @Atomzwieback as this is a mockup the keys like "attributes2" & "attributes1" are changing as it could anything like "abc","foo" so when i map to my model it breaks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need the [Record<T1, T2>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) interface but if you're looking to generate typings from data, then yes, http://json2ts.com/ is the best tool.

I wrote a poor version of that and tested with your model:

```
interface ITest {
  attributes1: {
    myKey1: {
      myinnerKey11: {
        value: string,
        name: string
      },
      myinnerKey12: {
        value: string,
        name: string,
        otherKey: string
      }
    }
  },
  attributes2: {
    myKey2: {
      myinnerKey21: {
        value: string,
        name: string
      },
      myinnerKey22: {
        value: string,
        name: string,
        otherKey: string
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can try it here https://json2dts.stackblitz.io/ and the source code is at https://stackblitz.com/edit/json2dts.

As you can see, it is very simplistic and does not try to pattern match at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface iData {
  "attributes1": {
    "myKey1": {
      "myinnerKey11": {
        value: string,
        name: string,
        otherKey?: string
      },
      "myinnerKey12": {
        value: string,
        name: string,
        otherKey?: string
      }
    }
  },
  "attributes2": {
    "myKey2": {
      "myinnerKey21": {
        value: string,
        name: string,
        otherKey?: string
      },
      "myinnerKey22": {
        value: string,
        name: string,
        otherKey?: string
      }
    }
  }
}

const data: iData = {
  "attributes1": {
    "myKey1": {
      "myinnerKey11": {
        "value": "value 1",
        "name": "name 1"
      },
      "myinnerKey12": {
        "value": "value 1",
        "name": "name 1",
        "otherKey": "key 2"
      }
    }
  },
  "attributes2": {
    "myKey2": {
      "myinnerKey21": {
        "value": "value 1",
        "name": "name 1"
      },
      "myinnerKey22": {
        "value": "value 1",
        "name": "name 1",
        "otherKey": "key 2"
      }
    }
  }
};
```